# CSV file is not in the proper format after uploading it online

Tags: ruby, perl, csv

I created a CSV file while would look like this

```
 Name    Number    Marks   ID
 Raj     1234      100     1111
 kumar   2345      200    332
```

This file was in correct format in my local system as each field is in seperate column

I  have to send this file in email

But after sending the email the format changes like this

```
Name,Number,Marks,ID
Raj,1234,100,1111
kumar,2345,200,332
```

I dono why does this problem occurs?

Comment: What does this have to do w/programming?  The file changes from not being a CSV file to being a CSV file after being emailed?

Comment: Why do you call it "not proper format"? It is correct CSV file.

Comment: Has nothing to do with programming

Comment: There are a couple of (incorrect) assumptions you have made. For example: `I created a CSV file` - How? In what program? 2) `it looks like this` - where does it look like that? In a text editor? In an image? 3) `This file was in correct format` -- How did you check that? What program? 4) `After sending the format changes` --- How do you know that? What changed, your sent mail, or your original file? 5) You said you were "uploading" the file online, and sending it via email. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it has put comma's in is due to the file type you have used.

CSV stands for "comma seperated values" [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

You will need to change to format of the file if you do not want the comma's in the output.